# Want just the filename to show in array and not the whole path

Tags: android, arraylist, path

I need to get just file name of the files in my App folder but it is coming up with the whole path/storage/emulated/0/AppFolder/file1.pdf. How cani just have File.pdf show instead of the whole path. Please advise

```
 ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
File file[] =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/AppFolder").listFiles();
    recursiveFileFind(file);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<File>(ViewInspection.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files));
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + files.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void recursiveFileFind(File[] file1) {
    int i = 0;
    String filePath = "";
    if (file1 != null) {
        while (i != file1.length) {
            filePath = file1[i].getAbsolutePath();
            files.add(file1[i]);
            if (file1[i].isDirectory()) {
                File file[] = file1[i].listFiles();
                recursiveFileFind(file);
            }else{
                            }

            i++;
            Log.d(i + "", filePath);
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Have you checked the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName())?

Comment: Sounds like you want to get the name of the file, use .getName()

Comment: @curtisLeow i did and tried few but had no luck

Answer (score 0):

Use File.getName() instead of File.getAbsolutePath()

```
    while (i != file1.length) {
        filePath = file1[i].getName();// here
        files.add(file1[i].getName());//Updated here
         if (file1[i].isDirectory()) {
             File file[] = file1[i].listFiles();
             recursiveFileFind(file);
            }

             i++;
             //Log.d(i + "", filePath);
//Update
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
```

Comment: tried that. By doing that, it doesn't show anything

Comment: don't you get anything in log?

Comment: i just tried it again with getName() and it shows me the same output for the path

Comment: You used Log.d(i + "", filePath); to print the filename in the logcat trace. So check for the log in logcat. Else use toast to display the filepath.

Comment: yes, filepath shows what i want to se, but not sure how i can get that to the adapter. Not really good with adapter so it shows on my device. Appreciate your help with this

Comment: See my edit now. Added  files.add(file1[i].getName());//Updated here

Comment: files.add(file1[i].getName())- gives me error on add

Answer (score 0):

Change the files arraylist of File to arraylist of String. Change the following

```
ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();//Updated
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
File file[] =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/AppFolder").listFiles();
    recursiveFileFind(file);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewInspection.this,//Updated
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files));
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + files.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here:

You create an Adapter of `File`, by default `ArrayAdapter` will use `.toString()` of the object which it contains (in this case is File).

The `.toString()` of `File` is

```
public String toString() {
    return getPath();
}
```

`getPath` will return the abstract pathname.

```
 * Converts this abstract pathname into a pathname string.  The resulting
 * string uses the {@link #separator default name-separator character} to
 * separate the names in the name sequence.
 *
 * @return  The string form of this abstract pathname
```

Since you want to get the name the solution could be vary. The faster would be to use `<String>` instead of `<File>` and edit your code as:

```
filePath = file1[i].getAbsolutePath();
files.add(file1[i].getName());
```

But, if you want to get the `File` instance from the `ArrayAdapter` this solution could not help you.

You could:

1. Create something like a "wrapper" class, which will contains info about the File and have  a overrided `.toString()` which will print the File name.
   A wrapper class like:

   ```
   public static class FileWrapper {
       private final File file;
       private final String fileName;

       public FileWrapper(File file)
       {
           this.file = file;
           this.fileName = file.getName();
       }   

       public File getFile() { return file; } 

       @Override
       public String toString()
       {
           return fileName;
       }
   }
   ```

   then use `<FileWrapper>` and you will get the right name, and use `getItem(position).getFile()` to get the file instance. **Warning** I used `static` because i think it's better if you declare this class as an inner class, but if you not remove `static`
2. Create a subclass of `ArrayAdapter` (or, `BaseAdapter` which i prefer but) and override `getView` to suit your needs. I didn't tried this solution, but i found it a bit harder since you should save the inflater, the resource to use and then inflate and edit the text.

If you care only about "show files name", you could just do the first edit and you are OK.